# php-fpm doesn't create .sock file

Tags: php, centos, php-7

I have an AWS server running on Amazon Linux.

I used this guide to install php7 (bottom of the page): https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=695576

I would like to use nginx instead of Apache, so I've also installed the php70w-fpm and nginx packages. However, when I  `service start php-fpm`, it does not create a php-fpm.sock file anywhere on my server. I have checked in /var/run and have also ran `find / -name "*.sock"` which only returns `/var/run/rpcbind.sock`.

Comment: Is fpm configured properly , see file `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/<config>.conf` file  ?

Comment: I found my answer in that file, it wasn't pointing to any socket file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit: The real solution here is that the listen in `www.conf` and `fastcgi_pass` in nginx configuration have to match. Whether you use sockets or tcp is up to you.

The answer was to not use a `.sock` file at all.

### in `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` it has:

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

#### So in my nginx config I put

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

#### Instead of using something like

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
```

Comment: This is not really an answer, just an alternative solution. The question at hand is specifically regarding socket files, not TCP/IP

Comment: PHP FPM is usually easier to set up on TCP/IP but therefore slower.

Comment: @nito This is true however sockets can only handle a very small amount of traffic.

Comment: works for php7 + centos7 + nginx^^ no .sock file gets created on `service start` (permissions? not sure), either way this one works^

Comment: This answer helped me a lot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15424808/104380

Answer (score 14):

1. Make sure you have the following folder and that it's writable.
   `/var/run/php-fpm`
2. then in your `www.conf` you put:
   `listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock`
3. then run: 
   `sudo service php-fpm restart`
4. then update your `nginx.conf`:
   `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;`
5. and finally restart nginx:
   `sudo service nginx restart`

Comment: What do you need `fastcgi_param` to be if you are hosting multple sites? Can you reuse a single socket?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem - no socket created - and the same solution that Phil had.

I had just copy-pasted a pool-file, and only changed the socket-name in the listen-section. No socket.

This was because the pool name was already in use. When you already have pool with the same name, then there is not created a new socket.

So it is important to have a unique pool name for each socket.

So when copy/paste a pool configuration: Change both pool-name and socket-name!

Comment: This had been driving me nuts for hours. I'd copied a previous config file and forgot to change the [pool-name] - thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I missed in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/wordpress.conf` the correct section

```
[wordpress]
listen = /var/run/php7-fpm-wordpress.sock
```

The *.sock file is not created from filename but from section name.

Comment: Hallelujah! :D I also just forgot to change the "pool name" (did you mean this by "section") after copy and pasting from another config file.

Answer (score 3):

I had the error, because I copy-pasted a pool.d/xx.conf and the new one had the same pool name [whatever], so the second was not loaded.
No error, no socket.

Hope that helps someone :)

Answer (score 2):

I know its too late, but may be this can help. You can create a new lock file from the scratch using Python.

```
python -c "import socket as s; sock = s.socket(s.AF_UNIX); sock.bind('/run/php/php-fpm.sock')"
```

Answer (score 2):

If your php-fpm is controlled by `systemd` you have to check `PrivateTmp` option in your php-fpm service unit file (you can this file this way `find /etc/systemd -name "php-fpm*" ! -type d`)

If this option is set to true `PrivateTmp=true`, new file system namespace will be created for php-fpm master process and other process will be unable to manipulate files in this namespace by default (nginx, for example). You can read more details about systemd `PrivateTmp` option here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In my case when changing PHP version example to PHP7.4 for a specific website in Ispconfig 3.2.2 the webxx.conf file should have been created in `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/` but instead, it was created at root `/`.

So for now I just mv the webxx.conf file to `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/` and restart PHP7.4-fpm `sudo systemctl restart php7.4-fpm` and it works correctly.