# php5-fpm.sock not found / created in /var/run

Tags: php, nginx, fpm

I fail to connect to php5-fpm.sock. I have tried many solutions but still getting this error:

```
2017/11/20 11:17:21 [crit] 9670#9670: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.224.8, server: babylon, request: "GET /webmail/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "babylon"
```

My configuration is  like this:

```
location /webmail {
        alias /srv/roundcubemail;
        index index.php index.html;
        # Favicon
        location ~ ^/webmail/favicon.ico$ {
                root /srv/roundcubemail/skins/classic/images;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
                expires max;
        }
        # Robots file
        location ~ ^/webmail/robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }
        # Deny Protected directories 
        location ~ ^/webmail/(config|temp|logs)/ {
                 deny all;
        }
        location ~ ^/webmail/(README|INSTALL|LICENSE|CHANGELOG|UPGRADING)$ {
                deny all;
        }
        location ~ ^/webmail/(bin|SQL)/ {
                deny all;
        }
        # Hide .md files
        location ~ ^/webmail/(.+\.md)$ {
                deny all;
        }
        # Hide all dot files
        location ~ ^/webmail/\. {
                deny all;
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
        }
        #Roundcube fastcgi config
        location ~ /webmail(/.*\.php)$ {
                error_log /var/log/nginx/x.log error;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^/webmail/(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/roundcubemail/$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/roundcubemail/index.php;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }
}
```

Is it maybe a problem with permissions over directories? I don't think so. 
The attempts that I made were:

- I change the listen of my www.conf, for socket and IP but still not working

  ; Unix user/group of processes
  ; Note: The user is mandatory. If the group is not set, the default user's group
  ;       will be used.
  user = www-data
  group = www-data

  ; The address on which to accept FastCGI requests.
  ; Valid syntaxes are:
  ;   'ip.add.re.ss:port'    - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific address on
  ;                            a specific port;
  ;   'port'                 - to listen on a TCP socket to all addresses on a
  ;                            specific port;
  ;   '/path/to/unix/socket' - to listen on a unix socket.
  ; Note: This value is mandatory.
  listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
  ;listen = 127.0.0.1:9000

  ; Set listen(2) backlog.
  ; Default Value: 65535 (-1 on FreeBSD and OpenBSD)
  ;listen.backlog = 65535

  ; Set permissions for unix socket, if one is used. In Linux, read/write
  ; permissions must be set in order to allow connections from a web server. Many
  ; BSD-derived systems allow connections regardless of permissions. 
  ; Default Values: user and group are set as the running user
  ;                 mode is set to 0660
  listen.owner = www-data
  listen.group = www-data
  listen.mode = 0660
- I have restarted php5-fm and nginx and still nothing.

Any ideas how I can fix that?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo lsof -c php-fpm | grep -i sock`, please add that to your question

Comment: This answer will solve your problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57956896/12074217

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, ensure that [php-fpm](https://php-fpm.org/) is installed, you could use this to check the current version if any:

```
php-fpm -v
```

Second check the `php-fpm.conf` configuration, and search for this line:

```
listen = /tmp/php-fpm.socket
```

In case it doesn't exist just add it, it can be also something like:

```
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
```

In some Linux distros normally this is used:

```
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
```

In case you want to use a TCP socket:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Restart `php-fpm` and check that the socket has been created in case of using a [Unix domain socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket), this can be done by doing this:

```
$ file /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
```

If socket exists if should print out something like this:

```
/var/run/php5-fpm.sock: socket
```

Comment: In your answer, I think `fmp` should be `fpm` .

Comment: I seem to **not have** a `php-fpm.conf`. On Manjaro when I run `whereis php-fpm.conf` I just get a binary and a manual, nothing else, which suggests that it doesn't exist.

Comment: Ignore me, I should have used `locate php-fpm.conf`. Thanks

Comment: working with me php 7.3
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx

Answer (score 2):

Could you please ensure those settings on your PHP-fpm/www.conf file

```
.....
user = www-data
group = www-data

listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
......
```

Then Restart PHP-fpm under root user.

Answer (score 0):

```
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
```