# Wordpress White Screeen Of Death on fresh install

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I have downloaded wordpress on a web server, and am serving it with nginx. Accessing `example.com/readme.html` works fine but `example.com/` or `example.com/wp-admin/install.php` returns a white screen.

I am using `php 7.4`, `php7.4-fpm`, `nginx 1.18.0`.

This is the location block of my nginx config file

```
location / {
                root /var/www/wordpress;
                index index.php;
                
                location ~ \.php$ {
                    try_files $uri =404;
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    include fastcgi_params;
                }
        
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

In my `wp-config.php` I have the following

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/');
```

But no error log is found in wp-content after loading the page.

I have tried

- Restarting nginx and php-fpm
- Changing memory limits in `/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini`
- changing `wp-content/plugins` to `wp-content/plugins_old`
- setting all file permissions to 777 (Bad practice, I know)
- Checking browser debuggers for errors (empty)
- Checking nginx and php logs for errors (empty)

Edit: error found in nginx error.log

```
2022/01/07 00:33:32 [crit] 339913#339913: *1414 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: [redacted], server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

Comment: What's the HTTP status code you receive on the blank pages?

Comment: @jrswgtr Checking the network tab of my browser it there is only a 200 OK response.

Comment: Did you check nginx log file? It should be under /var/log/nginx

Comment: @SergioRinaudo Huh. I just checked the log files and theres something that wasn't there previously. I have edited the question to reflect the error.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31905948/11556921). Issue was incorrect nginx configuration for php-fpm, added `include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;` and all was good.